# Firebase Cloud Messaging with Flutter and ASP NET CORE

Tags: flutter, asp.net-core, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an ordering application for a pastry shop where the customer sends the following data to an API created by me: `CustomerName`, `telephone number`, P`astryName`, `quantity`, `address`... My API saves this data in my SQL SERVER database. However, I'm having difficulty applying it to the bakery owner, as I'm new to Firebase and can't configure anything. I needed that when the customer posts all the information in the database, Firebase automatically sends a notification to the bakery owner with all the message data, such as telephone number, customer name, pastry, quantity... for here it goes. Could anyone help me with what the entire configuration would look like in Firebase, ASP Net Core and Flutter?

I haven't been able to configure anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for the messaging feature? If so, refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#c on how you can send messages to a client.

Basically, your SQL Server needs to store a copy of your FCM token, which will be used for messaging. (Note that such token will be refreshed. Your API has to find a way to sync the token to make sure such token is update-to-date). And whenever a customer posts something, your API will have to send a message afterwards.

Regarding how your client app should handle the messages received, see https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage. Overall, with the help of the firebase messaging package, your client can actively listen for any messages and perform actions in response to them.

This is just the overview of how the feature you mentioned can be configured. Feel free to let me know if you need more detailed information.